# first homology group $H_{1}(R,\mathbb {Z})$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, riemann-surfaces

Where can I find a good construction (book, notes, videotapes on youtube ...) about 
$$H_{1}(R,\mathbb{Z}).$$ 
Where R is a Riemann surface closed.

In fact, I need a little more ... a reference on Rham cohomology would also be helpful! I need to learn Sheaf Cohomology.

Thank you.

Comment: What is $R$ here? What kind of cohomology are you thinking about?

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud I edited to improve the question. thank you!

Comment: For coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$, deRham cohomology is not what you are looking for. Singular cohomology is more suited. I am unsure about sheaf cohomology (I am ashamed to say that I have never really learned it)

Comment: Also, it is standard to write $H^1$ for cohomology, and $H_1$ for homology.

Comment: I know it's different things ... I've read a little about it in the past. But I wanted to read more closely at this time.

Comment: Well, singular and deRham cohomology are very closely linked: for smooth manifolds, deRham cohomology is canonically isomorphic to singular cohomology with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: For sheaf cohomology you can take a look in the book of Forster, lectures on Riemann surfaces.